# matplotlib: Can I interrupt an `axhline` with text?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

In a plot, I would like to draw an `axhline` in a particular plot which is annotated by its value, a bit like the contour plot example [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html). E.g. looking something like: `--------- 0.13 -----------`.

Is this possible in `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 15):

You can create a normal `text` object at the center point of the line and then set the [**background color**](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_backgroundcolor) to the color of the axes so that the horizontal line is not visible behind the text.

```
plt.axhline(linewidth=4, y=0.5, color='red')

plt.text(0.5, 0.5, 'text', fontsize=30, va='center', ha='center', backgroundcolor='w')
```

[image]

Comment: If x-axis is a date then what should be replaced with first 0.5 in ````plt.text(0.5, 0.5, 'text', fontsize=30, va='center', ha='center', backgroundcolor='w')````

Comment: the text has a white background. How can I remove this?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer The white background is necessary to "cover" the red line. You should be able to set it to be the same color as your `axes` instead

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add such an hline to a coloured image, the "white background"-approach will not work. Instead you can write a small helper function, which draws to lines interrupted by the text:

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def hline_text(x, y, text, color="k", fontsize=12, linestyle="-", ax=None):
    """ draw hline at y interrupted by text at x """
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    text = f" {text} "  # pad with single space
    label = ax.text(x, y, text, color=color, fontsize=fontsize,
                    va="center", ha="center")
    # draw text to get its bounding box
    ax.get_figure().canvas.draw()
    bbox = label.get_window_extent().transformed(ax.transData.inverted())
    # add hlines next to bounding box
    left, right = ax.get_xlim()
    ax.hlines([y]*2, [left, bbox.x1], [bbox.x0, right], color=color, linestyle=linestyle)

# draw gradient
x = np.arange(130).reshape((10, 13))
plt.imshow(x, interpolation='bilinear')
# add text & hline to current axes
hline_text(6, 7, "hello world")
plt.show()
```